# How to analyse the FFT output (Array [512])?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, signal-processing, fft

What do the values of a FFT output means?

I'm using AudioKit's FFT algorithm (framework written for Swift) and when I fft the AudioNode (the microphone sound), it gives me a variable containing the fft data. It's a variable of 512 positions (0 to 511).

When I do it, it gives me veeeery small results, like 0.00004231 or even 2.41233e-7, sometimes 2.41233e-12. What do these values means?

What I think:

```
    index 0: 0 - x Hz
          1: x - 2x Hz
          2: 2x- 3x Hz
          ::
          ::
          and so on...

    Each array has the Amplitude value of that position.
```

Am I right? If no, please explain me. It will help me a lot.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, I know what a FFT does, but I don't know how to read the output data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Fourier Transform* maps a signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. As such, each FFT sample measures that given frequency intensity in the original signal.

For instance, `fft[2]` indicates how strong frequency 2 hz is in the original signal. Keep in mind there might be some scaling in the `fft` array returned by [AudioKit](http://audiokit.io/docs/), so please check the actual frequency range covered by those 512 samples.

Comment: Well, each index of the array shows me what? The amplitude? Like I said in the question, is my thought valid?

Comment: @DenisCandido Yes, in general terms, you are on the right track as well!

Comment: @DenisCandido ...but please keep in mind that the FFT signal range (e.g., fft[2]) isn't in the same unit as the original signal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try to train a neural network with a lot of this data. Do you think it will get good results?

Comment: @DenisCandido It really depends on the neural net design. But if you plan to detect a given signal main frequencies then FFT is solid/fast choice!

Comment: I saw an answer saying that it walks by 40Hz on each index (I.e. [0~40,40~80,...]) but I lost this question and created this to confirm my thought. Nice to hear that it's a good choice as I gave up on frequency analysis(using logic) to detect chord. It's as complex as voice recognition.